# GA-B150M-D3H motherboard and PCIe NVMe 3.0 x4 ssd

Tags: motherboard, ssd, data-storage, pcie, intel

**GA-B150M-D3H** - https://www.gigabyte.com/Motherboard/GA-B150M-D3H-rev-10/sp#sp :

Storage Interface:

1 x M.2 Socket 3 connector (Socket 3, M key, type 2242/2260/2280 SATA & PCIe x4/x2/x1 SSD support)

**PCIe NVMe 3.0 x4 ssd** - https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark/products/149407/intel-ssd-660p-series-1-0tb-m-2-80mm-pcie-3-0-x4-3d2-qlc.html

Is it compatible?

Thank you